# Detecting a dotted line among contours in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, vision

Tricky one today, but definitely do-able and I think I'm on the right track.  I'm trying to detect a dotted line in an image.  I do this by finding pairs of the best fit contours whose's slopes also align with the angle created by each other.  See example chunk of code below:

```
//Get canny mat
Mat frame, framegray, detectededges, dummyimg, cannyedges;
cvtColor(frame, framegray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(framegray, detectededges, Size(3,3));
double otsu_thresh_val = cv::threshold(detectededges, dummyimg,0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::Canny( detectededges, cannyedges, otsu_thresh_val*0.5, otsu_thresh_val );

//
Scalar color(255,255,0,255);

//Find contours
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(cannyedges,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double contourlength = arcLength(contours[idx], false);
vector<Vec4f> vectorofbestfits;

//Find dotted lines
for (vector<Point> contour : contours){
    //Some filtering
    if ((contourlength > 70.0) && (contours[idx].size() > 5)){
        Vec4f bestfitline;
        fitLine(contour, bestfitline,CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01);
        vectorofbestfits.push_back(bestfitline);
    }
}

float mtol = 0.05;
for (Vec4f veci : vectorofbestfits){
    float mi = veci[1]/veci[0];
    for (Vec4f vecj : vectorofbestfits){
        float mj = vecj[1]/vecj[0];
        double length = cv::norm(Mat(Point(veci[2],veci[3])),Mat(Point(vecj[2],vecj[3])));
        if (length < 30){
            continue;
        }
        float mk = (veci[3]-vecj[3])/(veci[2]-vecj[2]);
        mi = abs(mi);
        mj = abs(mj);
        mk = abs(mk);
        float mij = abs(mi - mj);
        float mjk = abs(mj - mk);
        float mki = abs(mk - mi);
        if ((mij < mtol) && (mjk < mtol) && (mki < mtol)){
            line(frame,Point(veci[2],veci[3]),Point(vecj[2],vecj[3]),color,2);
        }
    }
}
```

Methodology is:
1) Create an array of best fit lines to the contours
2) Step through array and get slope of line
3) Step through array again and slope of every other line
4) Calculate the slope of line created by the two line centers
5) Compare all 3 slopes against each other and filter with a tolerance value

The code below generates a ton of lines from my image, but none of them hit the obvious dotted line.  I'm thinking something isn't right with the slope calculations.  Right now it's so ineffective I need to create some images and test instead of working with real world graphics.  Anything jump out?

Also, the code below is pretty computationally heavy, the application is for video interpretation and framerate is critical, so any suggestions to improve performance are appreciated.

Looking for matches like so:
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ocwyu-SgDablc0ZDZQbHFoNW1LX0d1M2NqXzNERTVrNjVj/view?usp=drivesdk)

---

Edit:

Here's some cleaner code to read.  I also realized taking the absolute value of the slopes BEFORE finding the difference didn't make any sense and just create a bunch more incidental contours that matched up.  I need to play with it some more to see if that helped:

```
//Get canny mat
Mat frame, framegray, detectededges, dummyimg, cannyedges;
cvtColor(frame, framegray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(framegray, detectededges, Size(3,3));
double otsu_thresh_val = cv::threshold(detectededges, dummyimg,0, 255,
    CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::Canny( detectededges, cannyedges, otsu_thresh_val*0.5, otsu_thresh_val );

//Set color for Lines
Scalar color(255,255,0,255);

//Find contours
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(cannyedges,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double contourlength = arcLength(contours[idx], false);
vector<Vec4f> arrayofbestfits;

//Create an array of best fit Lines
for (vector<Point> contour : contours){
    //Filter out contours that are too small
    if ((contourlength > 70.0) && (contours[idx].size() > 5)){
        Vec4f bestfitLine;
        fitLine(contour, bestfitLine,CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01);
        arrayofbestfits.push_back(bestfitLine);
    }
}

float SlopeTolerance = 0.05;
for (Vec4f firstIterationLine : arrayofbestfits){
    float firstIterationSlope = firstIterationLine[1]/firstIterationLine[0];
    for (Vec4f secondIterationLine : arrayofbestfits){
        //Filter out Lines too close in proxmity
        double length = cv::norm(Mat(Point(firstIterationLine[2],firstIterationLine[3])),
            Mat(Point(secondIterationLine[2],secondIterationLine[3])));
        if (length < 30){
            continue;
        }
        //Find slope between two points
        float commonSlope = (firstIterationLine[3]-secondIterationLine[3])
            /(firstIterationLine[2]-secondIterationLine[2]);
        //Find absolute value of differences (makes comparison simpler)
        float commonSlopediff = abs(firstIterationSlope - secondIterationSlope);
        float secondtocommonSlopediff = abs(secondIterationSlope - commonSlope);
        float commontofirstSlopediff = abs(commonSlope - firstIterationSlope);
        //If within tolerances draw the line bridging the two best fit lines together
        if ((commonSlopediff < SlopeTolerance) && (secondtocommonSlopediff < SlopeTolerance) && (commontofirstSlopediff < SlopeTolerance)){
            Line(frame,Point(firstIterationLine[2],firstIterationLine[3]),
                Point(secondIterationLine[2],secondIterationLine[3]),color,2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer, a 'segmented' line is what I'm searching for among the contours.  That's why I examine the slope of the contour itself.

Comment: tbh I wouldnt have segmented the bottom left line the way you did. But I would have segmented one more line at bottom left. About your code: can you comment or rename the variables to get a faster understanding of their intended meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example image, it looks like you're trying to detect line segments with the following constraints:

1. segments have similar slopes (or orientations)
2. segments fall along similar line.

This problem seems really well suited for a [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) solution.

---

With simple 2D RANSAC, you are finding the line that most of your data points align with.

1. You solve for this line by randomly sampling subsets (in this case, subsets of 2) and connecting the points in the subsets.
2. Then, you set a window size, and include all other points that lie within the line joining your subset +/- the window size. 
   These points are called inliers.
3. You want to find the line segment that maximizes the number of inliers.

For more information see [these slides on RANSAC](http://soe.rutgers.edu/~meer/TEACH/ADD/myransac.pdf)

---

In your case, you want to modify the problem slightly to reflect the fact that you are looking for line segments, not points.
There are many ways of accomplishing this.

One solution is to cluster your segments based on slope, then apply simple 2D RANSAC to each cluster, and treat the segments as if they were points.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that is extremely helpful,  Also, the external links on the wikipedia link have a lot of opencv examples.    Additionally, my code actually seems to work after removal of the ABS() before slope comparison, but the RANSAC may be a more proven solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Glad you were able to get your code working.